# Query SharePoint List - Lookup Field & return Value not ID Using SQL

Tags: sql, sharepoint, adodb

I am trying to query SharePoint list using SQL to return a set of configurations. My current SQL statement is:

SELECT [CheckName],[FRAG Status], [Checkleveltype],[Comments] FROM [Default] WHERE [Run Check Flag] = True

Field 'CheckName' is a lookup field. How can I return the value / label of this field rather than the ID.

Thanks